# Where to put non-ui logic in react/redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm writing a react/redux app that has a Job object that fires Events from time to time. On these Events the user is expected to react. I can easily write the React component that shows such a job or events, but don't know where to put the logic when

- the user is not on the Job page
- and an Event happens
- and I would like to pop up a notification

Of course, once I get access to the store, I can create the notification too.

1. Shall I handle such logic in a React container that `render()` nothing?
2. Or handle it with vanilla JS when I load a Job data?
3. Or to handle it in the reducer when the data is stored? (probably not recommended)

My problem with the option two is that I don't know how to access the redux store from a totally ad-hoc code, as my store is not a global object.

What do you recommend?

Comment: Assuming you are loading the data asynchronously, you could fire a SHOW_NOTIFICATION action or similar? Alternatively, you could export your store when you create it, and import it wherever you need to subscribe to changes.

Comment: What would trigger the job events if not the user? web sockets? worker thread? timer of some kind?

Comment: I would put a `Notifications` component under your root component, that listens for such events and show the notifications when needed.

Comment: @azium, the job events are timed, and the timing is received together with the job data, simple setTimeout would work, just I don't know where to put it

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, the two places that you'd put code that needs to access the store (for either dispatching or receiving state updates) is in middleware or a connected component.  If you specifically want to respond to an action coming through, then you would need to use middleware.

I actually threw together a sample timer middleware in a chat discussion a few weeks ago.  I just pasted it as a gist here as an example: https://gist.github.com/markerikson/ca96a82d6fdb29388aca4052a9455431 .  Illustrates the idea of doing something asynchronously in the background.

You may also want to look through the list of middlewares in my Redux addons catalog: https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/middleware.md .  Numerous examples of ways to execute background-ish logic.

Finally, https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga (which is itself a middleware) is a fairly common lib used to do background-ish logic.